# Replace content of HTML tag text with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, markup

If i for example have this markup:

```
<p>
    <br />
    TEXT TEXT TEXT KEYWORD
    <span>TEXT TEXT TEXT</span>
</p>
```

How do i replace the KEYWORD text with some anchor element so it would turn to be:

```
<p>
    <br />
    TEXT TEXT TEXT <a href="www.url.com">KEYWORD</a>
    <span>TEXT TEXT TEXT</span>
</p>
```

I have tried using the HtmlNodeNavigator Value attribute, it seems it has only the text characters (not all the InnerText with the children elements included) of the current navigation element and its siblings and children.

BUT when i tried to use the SetValue (because the Value is only a getter) it throw an error saying "Specified method is not supported.".

I don't really know why this happens.

I didn't find any other method to change the text.

This is the code i'm running to find a keyword text in HTML markup and set it as a link.

I know it's not done yet but i'm stuck with the part of replacing and getting new text instead of the old one. Notice its a recursive method.

```
private  static void FindKeyword(string keyword, string url, HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeNavigator nav)
    {
        while (!nav.IsEmptyElement && nav.InnerXml.Contains(keyword))
        {
            if (nav.Value.Contains(keyword) && nav.Name != "a")
            {
                string newStr = nav.Value.Replace(keyword, "<a href=\"" + url + "\">" + keyword + "</a>");

                nav.SetValue(newStr);//exception "Specified method is not supported"
            }

            if (nav.HasChildren)
            {
                nav.MoveToFirstChild();
                FindKeyword(keyword, url, nav); 
            }

            nav.MoveToNext();
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

Thanks

Comment: Here is my solution: This is my solution -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585100/find-keyword-in-text-when-keyword-match-certain-conditions-c-sharp/14685004#14685004

Answer (score -1):

why not just use [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)?

```
string input = "<p><br />TEXT TEXT TEXT KEYWORD<span>TEXT TEXT TEXT</span></p>";
input = input.Replace("KEYWORD", "<a href=\"www.url.com">KEYWORD</a>")
```

if you have more than one keywords then

```
string input = "<p><br />TEXT TEXT TEXT KEYWORD<span>TEXT TEXT TEXT</span></p>";
string[] keywords = { "KEYWORD1", "KEYWORD2" };
for(int i=0; i<keywords.Length; i++)
    input.replace(keyword[i],"<a href=\"www.url.com\">" + keyword[i] + "</a");
```

if you want add different links

```
string input = "<p><br />TEXT TEXT TEXT KEYWORD<span>TEXT TEXT TEXT</span></p>";
string[,] keyurls = { {"KEYWORD1","URL1"}, {"KEYWORD2","URL2"} };
for(int i=0; i<keyurls.GetLength(0); i++)
    input.replace(keyurls[i,0],"<a href=\"" + keyurls[i,1] + "\">" + keyurls[i,0] + "</a");
```

Comment: I can't use replace because there are times when the KEYWORD can appear as an attribute value of some element - where then i don't want it as a link (it will break the valid HTML).