# Create Html links from in-text Urls using Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

How can I convert a url to html link from text using Html Agility Pack + c#?

For example: "www.stackoverflow.com is a very cool site."

Output:

```
"<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">www.stackoverflow.com</a>  is a very cool site."
```

Comment: _Did you tried anything?_ Show your effort first..

Comment: I have tried using regex and it works but I wanted to try Html Agility pack if it can do this. I've done lot of research about using Html Agility pack and haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: Html Agility Pack works on HTML string. The string you give is not a full HTML fragment. Also, are quotes important/significant in your example? a piece of real c# code would help.

Comment: Can we just avoid making this a chain of comments. If I was struggling to achieve what I know how with Html agility pack I would've supplied the piece of code. All I want is a whether anyone has tried this and can confirm whether it's possible or not. Why a +1 to @SonerGönül?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @user1778606 for your answer. I got this working though it still uses a bit of Regex. It works much better and safer (i.e. it will never create hyperlinks within hyperlinks and the href attribute).

```
        //convert text to html
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(inputString);

        // \w* - means it can start with any alphanumeric charactar
        // \s+ - was placed to replace all white spaces (when there is more than one word).
        // \b - set bounderies for the keyword
        const string pattern = @"((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)";

        //get all elements text propery except for anchor element 
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[not(ancestor::a)]") ?? new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection(null);

        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            node.InnerHtml = regex.Replace(node.InnerHtml, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>").Replace("href=\"www", "href=\"http://www");
        }

        return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure its possible, although I haven't attempted it.

Here's how to replace a fixed string in a document with links

> [Find keyword in text when keyword match certain conditions - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585100/find-keyword-in-text-when-keyword-match-certain-conditions-c-sharp/14685004#14685004)

Heres how to regex for urls

> [regular expression for url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url)

Put those together and it should be possible.

Pseudocode

> select all text nodes
>
> > for each node
> >
> > > get the inner text 
> > >       find urls in the text (use regex?) 
> > >       for each url found
> > >
> > > > replace the text of the url with string literal link tag  (a href = etc ...)